# Anaconda PyCulib and CUDA Issues

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cuda, anaconda, gpu

I'm trying to use PyCulib for GPU calculations and Anaconda 5.1 with Python 3.6 in an Amazon Web Services Windows instance, I have PyCulib installed and CUDA 9.1.85_win10 installed but when ever I use an import relying on CUDA I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "findGPUs.py", line 4, in <module>
prng = curand.PRNG(rndtype=curand.PRNG.XORWOW)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 211, in _require_cuda_context
get_context()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 194, in get_context
return _runtime.get_or_create_context(devnum)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 162, in get_or_create_context
return self.push_context(self.gpus[devnum])
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 40, in __getitem__
return self.lst[devnum]
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devices.py", line 26, in __getattr__
numdev = driver.get_device_count()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 334, in get_device_count
self.cuDeviceGetCount(byref(count))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 272, in __getattr__
self.initialization_error)
numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError: Error at driver init:

CUDA driver library cannot be found.
If you are sure that a CUDA driver is installed,
try setting environment variable NUMBAPRO_CUDA_DRIVER
with the file path of the CUDA driver shared library.
:
```

The offending code is:

```
import numpy as np
from pyculib import rand as curand

prng = curand.PRNG(rndtype=curand.PRNG.XORWOW)
rand = np.empty(100000)
prng.uniform(rand)
print(rand[:10])
```

I think my main issue is that I just don't know where the CUDA driver shared lirary is.

My Path is:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\lib\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\extras\CUPTI\libx64
```

With the following variables:

```
CUDA_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1
CUDA_PATH_V9_1: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 36
```

Comment: The driver shared library is `nvcuda.dll`, usually located in `C:\Windows\System32`.  However I'm reasonably sure applications should find DLL's in this directory "automatically".  Not really sure what the issue is.  Did you validate your CUDA install?  Instructions for validation are in the CUDA windows install guide.

Comment: I can validate my CUDA Installation just fine, the problem will be that that .dll isn't there.

Comment: That statement makes no sense. For the CUDA installation to work, you *must* have the driver library installed, which is patr of the standard nvidia driver installation.

Comment: I'm able to verify my installation with nvcc -V giving me: 
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:08:12_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85. I did some more research and it would appear that my aws instance doesn't support what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That doesn't verify the CUDA installation.  I've already indicated to you where you can find a description of verification.  If your AWS instance is not a GPU-equipped instance, then you won't be able to perform GPU calculations with it, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved, I was using the wrong aws instance type for NVIDIA support.